# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't create an instance of class

Tags: java, java-native-interface

My requirement is do password validation using JNA and I have wrote sample codes for this.

I have a java class as below,

```
public enum _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE implements NativeMapped {
    NetValidateAuthentication,
    NetValidatePasswordChange,
    NetValidatePasswordReset;

        @Override
        public Object fromNative(Object nativeValue, FromNativeContext context) {
            return values()[(Integer) nativeValue];
         //return ordinal();
        }

        @Override
        public Object toNative() {
            //return values();
            return ordinal();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> nativeType() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
}
```

calling the above `enum` method in below interface method,

```
public int NetValidatePasswordPolicy(String servername, String qualifier, _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE validationType, LMAccess.NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG password, PointerByReference bufptr);
```

I have called the method from my service class,

```
_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE enumvalue = _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE.valueOf(_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE.class,"NetValidatePasswordChange");

Netapi32Extn.INSTANCE.NetValidatePasswordPolicy(null, null, enumvalue, input,bufptr);
```

while execute I'm getting the below error,

```
2018-10-07 17:37:06.821 ERROR 31616 --- [nio-7777-exec-2] com.merckgroup.biop.utils.LogFactory     : UserManagementController-Can't create an instance of class com.merckgroup.biop.win32.Netapi32Extn$_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE, requires a no-arg constructor: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.merckgroup.biop.win32.Netapi32Extn$_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't create an instance of class com.merckgroup.biop.win32.Netapi32Extn$_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE, requires a no-arg constructor: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.merckgroup.biop.win32.Netapi32Extn$_NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.defaultValue(NativeMappedConverter.java:65) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.<init>(NativeMappedConverter.java:55) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.getInstance(NativeMappedConverter.java:44) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:502) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:338) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.NetValidatePasswordPolicy(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.merckgroup.biop.services.WindowsManagementService.createAccount(WindowsManagementService.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.merckgroup.biop.services.UserManagementService.createUserAccount(UserManagementService.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.merckgroup.biop.services.UserManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a3a0f399.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.merckgroup.biop.services.UserManagementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55309853.createUserAccount(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.merckgroup.biop.controllers.UserManagementController.createUserAccount(UserManagementController.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:146) [spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81) [spring-session-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Could some one please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [NativeMapped docs](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/NativeMapped.html) states

> Implementations of this interface must provide a no-args constructor.

```
public enum _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE implements NativeMapped {
    NetValidateAuthentication,
    NetValidatePasswordChange,
    NetValidatePasswordReset;

    private _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE() { }

    @Override
    public Object fromNative(Object nativeValue, FromNativeContext context) {
        return values()[(Integer) nativeValue];
        //return ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public Object toNative() {
        //return values();
        return ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> nativeType() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: i m not able to create  public _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE() {
        super();
    }... shows illegal modifier for the enum constructor; only private is permitted.. also cannot invoke super constructor from enum constructor _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE()...

Comment: @DineshKumar Did you try with `private`?

Comment: yeah.. private i didnt get error.. but i m not able to declare super()..

Comment: public enum _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE implements NativeMapped{

     NetValidateAuthentication,
     NetValidatePasswordChange,
     NetValidatePasswordReset;
  
   private _NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE() {
          //super();
      }
Still getting same error after declare constructor also...